# Add product to cart works in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: httprequest, product, cart, magento2

I'm currently developing in Magento 2 and when i add a product to the cart, in Firefox the product is added to the cart and the minicart is updated correctly, yet, in Chrome, this doesn't happen.

Here's what i have gathered from the dev. console of both web browsers:

**Firefox:**

1. POST request to /magento/checkout/cart/add/uenc/ramdomString,,/product/idProduct/

This request has a Status code: 200 OK.

2. GET request to /magento/customer/section/load/?sections=cart,messsages&update_section_id=true&_=someNumber

This request has a Status code: 200 OK.

**Chrome:**

1. POST request to /magento/checkout/cart/add/uenc/ramdomString,,/product/idProduct/

This request has a Status code: 302 FOUND.

2. GET request to /magento/checkout/cart/

This request has a Status code: 200 OK.

3. GET request to /magento/customer/section/load/?sections=cart%2Cmesssages&update_section_id=true&_=someNumber

This request has a Status code: 200 OK.

---

As can be seen, the only difference is that Chrome has an additional GET request. I have observed that when this request is made the product is not added to the cart. I have seen this in all my Magento 2 projects (i have several testing projects and in all of them this is happening and some of them are just fresh installations with one category and one product).

Now, i know that if i get Status code: 302 FOUND the resource i've requested has redirected me to somewhere else...but why this doesn't happen in Firefox as well?

I uploaded two images showing more information:

Image 1 corresponds to the first (1.) step -request- in Firefox and Chrome and Image 2 corresponds to the answer of the second step (2.) in Firefox and the third step (3.) in Chrome.

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjhuq.jpg
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HSEt.jpg

I have checked and it doesn't appear to be a cache problem.

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Thank you.

PS: Neither in Firefox nor in Chrome, updating products within the minicart or within /magento/checkout/cart works as expected.

Comment: did you found any solution